# toString() not working after unrelated changes. And I cannot locate toString() in WEKA, Java

Tags: java, weka, tostring

Recently I am working on WEKA, output the detailed rules of Random Forest.
The classes I am working on has the following hierarchical relationship:

```
public class RandomForest extends Classifier {
       public Bagging m_bagger;
       public String toString(){
              return "other"+m_bagger.toString(); 
       }
}
public class Bagging extends RandomizableIteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer{
       // no relative declaration
       public String toString(){
              return "other"+m_Classifiers[i].toString(); //changes I made
       }
}
public abstract class RandomizableIteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer extends IteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer {
       // no relative declaration 
       // no toString()
}
public abstract class IteratedSingleClassifierEnhancer extends SingleClassifierEnhancer{
       public Classifier[] m_Classifiers;
       // no toString()
}
public abstract class SingleClassifierEnhancer extends Classifier{
       protected Classifier m_Classifier = new ZeroR();
       // no toString()
}
public abstract class Classifier{
       // no toString()
}
```

Before I change it, the codes work well.
After I change it, if I read in the data and train a WEKA model myself, it also works very well.
However, if I load the model my professor gives me, then run the toString(), it reports these lines:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.leafString(RandomTree.java:656)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.toString(RandomTree.java:678)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.toString(RandomTree.java:707)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.toString(RandomTree.java:700)
```

It repeats these lines infinitely until I run out of memory.

I have debugged and find out the bug is at

```
m_Classifiers[i].toString()
```

The related codes are (in the class of RandomForest):

```
if (m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers == null) {
        System.out.println("Bagging: No model built yet.");
    } 
else {
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
        text.append("All the base classifiers: \n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers.length; i++)
              text.append(m_classifier.m_bagger.m_Classifiers[i].toString()+"\n\n");  //It goes wrong here

        if (m_classifier.m_bagger.m_CalcOutOfBag) {
            text.append("Out of bag error: "
                    + Utils.doubleToString(
                    m_classifier.m_bagger.m_OutOfBagError, 4)
                    + "\n\n");
    }
System.out.println(text.toString());
```

It behaves the same if I call methods (instead of use public variables).

An interesting fact is that I cannot locate the definition of this toString() at all. It reports "source not found" when I press F3 (in eclipse means go to definition) on this specific toString() (not others)
I have no idea where goes wrong, can somebody help me please?

Thank you a million.

Just for clarification:
It should not be the problem of index *i* since I have tried other functions like

```
m_Classifiers[i].debugTipText()
```

It works perfect.
For the same reason, I do not think m_Classifiers could be null
I changed some 'protected' to 'public', but it does not work before I make this change.

To respond to Jim's comment, here is the githup code for `RandomTree.java`
https://github.com/HaohanWang/WekaRandomForest/blob/master/src/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomTree.java
Sorry that I did not paste code here, because there are about 100 lines of relative code, through Line 626 to Line 715
There are actually more lines in the eclipse error,related to Line 656,Line 678 Line 700, Line 707, and Line 642. All these lines are calling either `leafString()` or `toString(int)`
Now I am guessing my problem is that I do not have an appropriate int for `toString(int)`

Comment: Show the complete statement that is throwing the exception.  If you're getting NPE in `m_Classifiers[i].toString()` the only possibilities are that `m_Classifiers[i]` is null or `m_Classifiers` is null.  Since you say the second is not the case, it must be the first, the value of the reference stored at `m_Classifiers[i]` is null.

Comment: Thanks, @JimGarrison I have updated the complete statement. However, I get results when I run `m_Classifiers[i].debugTipText()`. So I think maybe it is not the problem that `m_Classifiers[i]` is null. Thanks

Comment: Somewhere in the class hierarchy there is a `toString()` that depends on internal state that is null. What is at `weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree.leafString(RandomTree.java:656)`?

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison Please have a look to the post, I add the code and some explanation at the end.

Comment: Line 656 is `int maxIndex = Utils.maxIndex(m_Distribution[0]);` -- therefore `m_Distribution` is null. If `m_Distribution[0]` were null the error would have occurred inside `Utils.maxIndex` (I am assuming that `Utils.maxIndex()` is a static method).

Comment: That's true. Great! Thanks! Sorry that I did not think so much of the original source code of WEKA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 656 is

```
int maxIndex = Utils.maxIndex(m_Distribution[0]);
```

Therefore `m_Distribution` is null. If `m_Distribution[0]` were null the error would have occurred inside `Utils.maxIndex`, which I am assuming is a static method.